# PHP - SQL Query Returns array(0) { } when using var_dump

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

Im wondering why my Query is returning no data as title suggests

**My JQuery:**

```
$(".output").click(function() {
    var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
    $("#right-box").load("connectionDetails.php", { noteid: noteid });
});
```

**My connectionDetails.php**

```
<?php
$myServer = "replaced";
$connectionInfo = array('Database' => 'replaced', 'UID' => 'replaced', 'PWD' => 'replaced');

//connection to the database
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//Test connection to server
// if ($conn) 
// {
//     echo "connection successful";    # code...
// }

//Defining my queries
$getNotes = "SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes";
$getTemplateNotes = "SELECT TemplateNoteID, TemplateNoteName, TemplateNote FROM TemplateNotes";
$getReplaceVariables = "SELECT ReplaceVariableID, ReplaceVariableName, ReplaceVariableNote FROM ReplaceVariables";
$showNoteInfo = "SELECT Note FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = '" . isset($_POST['noteid']) . "'";

var_dump($_POST);

$resultNotes = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $getNotes );
$resultTemplate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getTemplateNotes);
$resultVariables = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getReplaceVariables);
$showNotes = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);




if( $resultNotes === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
if( $resultTemplate === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

if( $resultVariables === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

?>
```

**My index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Juan - Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/igotswag.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/swaganimations.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>


<!-- Header Area -->
<table class="header-container">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40%; text-align: left;"><a href="index.php"><img class="hover-cursor" src="Images/TEAMS_Logo.png"></a></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;" class="custom-header">TEAMS Wiki <span style="font-size: 30px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></td>
        <td style="width: 40%;">
            <table style="text-align: right; width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 24px; text-align: right;" class="hvr-icon-grow"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="pull-down-container">
    <div class="panel1">
        <br />
        <p>Now you see me!</p>
    </div>
    <p class="slide" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="pull-me hvr-icon-hang" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">More</div>
    </p>
</div>
<!-- End Header Area -->



<!-- Main Body Area -->

<div class="main-container-notes">
    <div id="left-box">
        <?php 

        echo "<div style='width: 100%;'>";

        while( $noteName = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor output' data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}' style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "</div>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">
       <?php 
            if ($note = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $showNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                echo $note['Note'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End Main Body Area -->


<!-- Footer Area -->

<!-- End Footer Area -->

</body>
</html>
```

In my main index there is a while loop that retrieves data fine from the database, each piece of data that comes through is given an ID from my SQL table with `data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}'` which is then assigned in my JQuery

So when i click on one of these generated divs it pulls extended text on the same page (hence the AJAX) depending on the ID

When i use var_dump($_POST) in my connectionDetails.php it returns array(0) { }

So why is it not finding any ID's?

Comment: SQL Injection Warning!!!

Comment: @JonStirling That's what I thought as well, however in the manual: `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`

Comment: @jeroen Good spot. I suppose it makes sense, though not exactly obvious.

Comment: When using `console.log(noteid)` after `var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");` what output you get?

Comment: I have just run a  very cut down version of this and it works. I am getting the post showing up. Just trying to see what is different..

Comment: @TimBrownlaw If you find out, if you could let me know that would be great! Thanks for looking

Comment: Done. That was fun :) See my answer below. Option 2 is what you want I would imagine...

Comment: @cmorrissey, SQL Injection? Where? I see just `isset` result concatenation..

Comment: @vp_arth ahhhh you are correct there, which is probably part of his problem as its always going to try to select note 1, if the `isset` is removed then it will be an SQL injection which is what I was looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm well I have grabbed just the basics from your code and built up some test code.

So we have...

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php include "test.php"; ?>

<script>
    $(".output").click(function () {
        var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
        console.log('Got here - Noteid = ' + noteid);
        $("#right-box").load("connectionDetails.php", {noteid: noteid});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Cut down version of your code of interest.**

**test.php**

```
<div id="left-box">
    <?php
    echo "<div style='width: 100%;'>";
    $noteName['NoteID']   = 1;
    $noteName['NoteName'] = 'Note 1';
    echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor output' data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}' 
          style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "
          </div>";

    $noteName['NoteID']   = 2;
    $noteName['NoteName'] = 'Note 2';
    echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor output' data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}' 
          style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "
          </div>";
    ?>
</div>
<div id="right-box">
</div>
```

And **connectionDetails.php** is

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

So this works... but moving the js segment above the include of test.php makes it not work.

Which shows that your js script needs to run after the page has loaded.
You currently have it before if I assume correctly that your JS is in `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>`

So you just have to move that to the end of the page... The DOM elements have to appear before the JS is called... But just checking if $(document).ready() helps out here...

**Option 2**
No need to change where your js includes are... just need to wrap your current js code like so...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".output").click(function () {
        var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
        console.log('Got here - Noteid = ' + noteid);
        $("#right-box").load("connectionDetails.php", {noteid: noteid});
    });
})
```

And as it implies, it will wait till the document loads and it will be happy...

In Most cases though you tend to load all your JS at the end of your page so things appear prior to any JS being fired...

**The Next Bit...**
This is really rough and ready and untested but the idea is there...

So just dealing with the main section of your connectionDetails.php, I have taken
the part dealing with the post aside...

```
   //... Your pre existing code here for the DB etc...  

   // Rewrite of this section of connectionDetails.php

    //Defining my queries
    $getNotes = "SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes";
    $getTemplateNotes = "SELECT TemplateNoteID, TemplateNoteName, TemplateNote FROM TemplateNotes";
    $getReplaceVariables = "SELECT ReplaceVariableID, ReplaceVariableName, ReplaceVariableNote FROM ReplaceVariables";

    $resultNotes = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $getNotes );
    $resultTemplate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getTemplateNotes);
    $resultVariables = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getReplaceVariables);

    // Still in development
    // ====================
    //  This is very rough and ready just for testing
    //  On Initial Page load, we don't have anything so this is okish
    if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) {
        $showNoteInfo = "SELECT Note FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = " . $_POST['noteid'];
        $showNotes    = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);
    }
    // *** The rest of your code ***
```

Remember this just a first go we can make a little better...

Comment: Just checking now, will report back shortly!

Comment: So its still returning as 0 in the var_dump, however if i use console log nothing at all shows in the console either its strange, ive got this in my js script `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".output").click(function () {
        var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
        console.log('Got here - Noteid = ' + noteid);
        $("#right-box").load("connectionDetails.php", {noteid: noteid});
    });
});` and my includes are at the bottom, im not really sure whats going on to be honest

Comment: and now im getting an error before that saying $ is not defined on line 1 which is `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Well make sure you are calling in your jquery.min.js before your js file. I have used your exact script src calls just to make sure.

Comment: Ooo, we are getting somewhere, it might be easier if you see for yourself, if you go to www.discovertheplanet.net and click the first notes box and click the notes down the side it shows something but not what im after. You will see what i mean, again, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: :) Now you're getting somewhere :)

Comment: I see in your scripts.js you have two document ready sections. You can simply put all your js inside the one document ready block.

Comment: Ok ive merged those together :) why is it not pulling through the note associated to that ID though instead its saying like: array(1) { ["noteid"]=> string(1) "1" } so when i click that note name it should pull through text from the 'Note' column in the database? i feel like ive done something in the #right-box code wrong but im not too sure what

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128888/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-luke-litherland).

Comment: I have replied in the discussion